# Jquery Datatables - if table header contains a column with name "URL", give hyperlink for that table column data

Tags: jquery, datatables

In a jquery data table, if table header contains a column with name "URL", give hyperlink for that table column data. I was unable to write the logic for this. Please help..

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var index = $('th:contains("Mar")').eq(0).index(); 
   $("tr").each(function(rowIndex, row){ 
     $(row).find("th:eq(" + index + ")").css('background', 'green'); 
     $(row).find("td:eq(" + index + ")").html('<a href="index">+index+'</a>'); 
}); 

});
```

I have tried the above code, but I want to have the urls with dynamic data

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the code..

Comment: @Zim84, 

$(document).ready(function(){
        var index = $('th:contains("Mar")').eq(0).index();
        $("tr").each(function(rowIndex, row){
            $(row).find("th:eq(" + index + ")").css('background', 'green');
            $(row).find("td:eq(" + index + ")").html('<a href="index">+index+'</a>');
        });
    });

I have tried the above code, but I want to have the urls with dynamic data.

Comment: You are using jquery datatable and have a column 'URL' where you want to give hyperlinks to that column.

Comment: @Rojen, I want to give hyperlinks for that column data(all tds for URL column)

Comment: Are you creating your own table or using  jquery dataTable

Comment: @Rojen, I am using Jquery dataTable

Comment: How are you sourcing data to the table via DOM or ajax or javascript

Comment: @Rojen, Via Ajax

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery datatable render example

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 5,
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.indexOf("partofyourlink") >-1) {
                return '<a href="http://somelink' + data + '.jpg">' + data + '</a>';
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

you can take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/fe9at67d/)

Comment: what does this mean "partofyourlink"?

Comment: it means the search content like "Mar"

Comment: please take a look in jsfiddle

Comment: partofyourlink is dynamic and sometimes the position can be changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'columns':[{
 'data': //your url data from json,
 render: function(data, type, row) {
     return '<a href= "'+ data +'"></a>"
            }
        }]
```